# Adobe AEM jQuery scroll event not firing

Tags: jquery, scroll, aem

I'm trying add a class to my nav-menu so that it assumes a fixed position after a certain amount of scrolling. Variations of this code work in a standard environment. However, AEM is not playing well with others. It will report the `$(window).scrollTop()` value in the console along with the value for `navMenuPos.top`. No matter what I try though, I cannot get it to say "Hi" to me. The scroll event appears to be not firing. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var navMenu = $('#nav-menu');
    var navMenuPos = $('#nav-menu').offset();

    console.log("Window scroll top is: " + $(window).scrollTop());
    console.log("The top of the top menu is: " + navMenuPos.top);

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        console.log("Hi");

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navMenuPos.top) {
            navMenu.addClass('fixed-pos-menu');
        }
        else {
            navMenu.removeClass('fixed-pos-menu');
        }

    });

});
```

In place of `$(window).scroll(function() {});` I've tried `$(window).bind('scroll', function() {});` and things like:

```
navMenu.on("scroll", function(e) {

    if (this.scrollTop > 147) {
        navMenu.addClass("fixed-pos-menu");
    } else {
        navMenu.removeClass("fixed-pos-menu");
    }

});
```

None of these things are triggering a scroll event.

The window object appears to be present as I can get information about its top. Maybe AEM doesn't see that as the scrolling part of the page?

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Are you able to see `Window scroll top is` log and not the `Hi`?. I did a small test, able to see scroll event log in console.

Comment: Absolutely bizarre. I tried it and it didn't fire, then I tried copy-pasting the code from my Stack Overflow post and it worked. I'm pretty sure it was a straight copy-paste from my original code. How odd. Thanks for your reply though! It made me give it another go.

Comment: Strange! Cool that it worked. In case you have a version control system and this file was part of that, see if there was any diff. Else it was machine playing games may be :). Though that doesn't happens normally